# Image Not Removing For Disable state of UIButton

Tags: swift, uibutton

I made a button that is able to toggle the own `isEnabled`, and It's updating the title and image of button according to this state.

```
myButton.setTitle("Enabled Title", for: .normal)
myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "enabled_resource_name"), for: .normal)

myButton.setTitle("Disabled Title", for: .disabled)
myButton.setImage(nil, for: .disabled)
```

The `isEnabled` of my button has toggled well. and title has also changed according to that.
But I found a strange problem about changing image.

In the `enabled` to `disabled` case, the image `UIImage(named: "enabled_resource_name")` doesn't removed.

But It has changed a little. the image has become a little transparent when It's disabled. and in the `disabled` to `enabled` case, It does work fine.

Why does this happens?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to set `UIImage()` instead of `nil`, like:

```
myButton.setImage(UIImage(), for: .disabled)
```

Comment: this's working correctly, but I think there's an error and someone should radar it maybe?